# Ruby - Selenium, disabling "reload page"

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chromium with selenium and recently I have a lot of these "reload page" popups.

```
def setup_selenium
require "selenium-webdriver" # load in the webdriver gem to interact with Selenium
require 'rubygems'

prefs = { # DISABLES GOOGLE PDF PREVIEWER PLUGIN.
          download: {
            'prompt_for_download' => false,
            'default_directory' => 'location'
          },
          plugins: {
            'always_open_pdf_externally' => true
          }
}

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument("-incognito");
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
options.add_argument('--disable-translate')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options, prefs: prefs
```

Even tho I have the `--disable-popup-blocking`, the popups still appear. I have seen many of these posts about the same problem, but non have given me the answer I need.

Gemfile

```
ruby '2.7.4'
gem 'headless', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.3'

gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.53', '>= 2.53.4'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't `disable-popup-blocking` actually allow popups?

Comment: changed `--disable-popup-blocking` to `disable-popup-blocking`, might have fixed it, but not 100%, sometimes they still appear. Thanks for the idea tho.

Comment: I suggest you to WATIR which is a wrapper around ruby selenium binding and post your question again using WATIR TAG.